# How to stop foul smell in toilet

Tags: toilet, gas, vent, smell, septic

My toilet always leaves some kind of foul smell not sure how it happens , all the toilets and septic tank has vent pipe too.

I personally checked my WC and it's properly attached with floor and it's been fused with floor using white cement so no gasket related issues as well.

Any ideas on how to go about fixing the problem.

Comment: Are you sure it is coming from the toilet?  Looks like a drain on the side also.

Comment: To me it smells kind of like sewer gas from septic tank ?

Comment: I meant from the toilet itself, from the bowl, or maybe from the floor drain nearby.  If the floor drain has not been used for weeks/months, it might have dry out the trap and letting gas/smells up.  Most drains have traps(bends in pipe) that keep some water in them to prevent gas/smells from coming back up.

Comment: @crip659 - You mean to say ,the water in Toilet bowl and drain trap bowl might be evaporating and the gas is the source of smell ?

Comment: @crip659 - Got it , there's no way the water can dry out in bowl as we use the toilet regularly. I'm confused on how to fix this

Comment: Imagine the toilet gets used often enough to keep water in it.  The floor drain might be dry and the smells are coming from it, instead of the toilet.  If dry from not being used(no floods in the room), might want to pour a gallon down it every week or two.  The floor drain I am talking about is the round thing on the floor by the door.

Comment: Makes sense , but I'm daily taking bath I'm sure water would be changed every now and then .. I'm thinking would there be invisible crack in toilet system so sewer gas escapes in ? Is there any way to determine the gas is indeed septic gas ?

Comment: Unless you pour your bathtub water down that floor drain, then that drain does not get used.  Water needs to go down each drain opening(they are all separate traps).

Comment: ok , will try and see thanks

Comment: @Amogam Just pour a bucket of water in to that drain and leave the door open for ventilation, see if the smell disappears over night.

Comment: Tried but didn't work though

Comment: Could there be something in the reservoir? I doubt mice can get in there, but if one did and it died...

Comment: but both septic and drainage line has water trap..still smell shouldn't read out right ?

Comment: @MiG - I think will have to open the trap and check out for any dead rodents. Thanks

Comment: Unless you lift the toilet, you don't know that the wax or rubber gasket is good.   They do fail.   And some plumbers say do NOT caulk around the toilet.   If there is a leak, you don't want it hidden.

Comment: @SteveWellens - That makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you have Air Vent that starts from the top most point of Septic tank , just in case water level raises in septic tank. This is mandatory
- Make sure there is a air vent for each toilet outlet
- Make sure the Air vent is not blocked by anything
- Make sure you wax ring is properly installed or make sure your sides of the WC is properly cemented with no air gaps.
- Use special toilet plunger to unclog the WC and near by lines , just in case
- Run the exhaust fan once in a while to stay away from mold and smells related to it.

FYI:

- Use flush tablets which prevents limescale build up and also has germicide
- Also keep air freshener in the bathroom to remove odours

Update:

- Make sure the water seal is not sucked in due to pressure loss in the pipe if the pressure loss happens you have to take a look into the plumbing system

Comment: I suspect microscopic air gaps. Probably will caulk it around the WC. Thanks